# Create BCP format file and bulk copy into the tables

Tags: sql, bcp

I'm trying to create bcp format file and bulk copy the data into the data base tables

I have used the command RunAs /netonly /user:domain\login BCP
It asked me for password to make sure that BCP will be able to access the database

then i gave a command

```
bcp DBName.Scheema.TableName format nul -f s:\bcp_TableName.xml -x -n -Sservername -Udomain\UserID
```

Microsoft ODBC driver 11 for swl server login failed user

I made sure that in server the authentication, selected the Sql server and windows authentication mode. but still im unable to change to BCP and import to table. Please help me